# Cannot add UISearchController to UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to add a `UISearchController` to a programatically created `UITableView`, in a `UIViewController` class. Here is my code:

```
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

var myTableView = UITableView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.bounds.width, view.bounds.height)
    myTableView.delegate = self
    myTableView.dataSource = self

    myTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self //ERROR
        controller.searchBar.delegate = self //ERROR
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        self.myTableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        return controller
    })()

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.addSubview(myTableView)

}
```

The two errors I get are

```
 - Cannot assign a value of type 'ViewController' to a value of type 'UISearchBarDelegate?
 - Cannot assign a value of type 'ViewController' to a value of type 'UISearchResultsUpdating?
```

This code works when my class is subclassed with `UITableViewController`. So why doesn't it work with `UIViewController?`

Comment: You need conform `UISearchBarDelegate`.

Comment: Did you add the delegates to the view controller? `class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate`

Comment: Thank you! This was my issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your `UIViewController` is conforming to the protocols `UISearchBarDelegate` and `UISearchResultsUpdating`.

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    // …truncated
}
```

`UITableViewController` automatically does this behind the scenes.